# python make_aio_client returns different types of objects

Tags: python

A puzzling question arose when using thriftpy2,this is my code：

```
async def callcentre(response, kwargs):
    client = await make_aio_client(
        echo_client.Dispather, '127.0.0.1', 8080
    )
    print(type(client))
    res = await client.tagsInfo(response, json.dumps(kwargs))
    return json.loads(res)
```

the type of the client is:

```
<class 'thriftpy2.contrib.aio.client.TAsyncClient'>
```

but when I remove await：

```
async def callcentre(response, kwargs):
    client =  make_aio_client(
        echo_client.Dispather, '127.0.0.1', 8080
    )
    print(type(client))
    res = await client.tagsInfo(response, json.dumps(kwargs))
    return json.loads(res)
```

the type of the client is:

```
<class 'generator'>
```

cause I can't call rpc's service

Why do it return different types of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `make_aio_client` is a *coroutine*, not just a regular python function. Since python 3.5 the `async` keyword indicates that function is a coroutine:

```
async def make_aio_client(...):
     ...
```

Regular function call won't actually execute it, just create a coroutine for you.

```
client =  make_aio_client(...
```

Roughly speaking, coroutines are just generators (functions that `yield` the result). That's why it's type is a `generator`.
You have to use the `await` keyword to schedule the execution in the *event loop*:

```
client_coro =  make_aio_client(
    echo_client.Dispather, '127.0.0.1', 8080
)
client = await client_coro()
```

Read the [asyncio manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) to learn more about coroutines and awaitables.